# Meaning of this character class in perl?

Tags: regular-expression, perl

I am new with PERL(though I have good background in reg-ex), I was going through one perl script and it has one characters class

```
$alwayssep = "[\\?!()\";/\\|‘]";
```

Can anyone explain to me what is the meaning of this? I can see it means any character including `?, !, (,),",;,/,|,'` but I don't understand why there are two backslash before question mark and pipe? Usually we use just one backslash to escape, is it different in perl?

Answer (score 4):

The code is a mess on account of the unfortunate use of double-quote interpolation to define the regex; the [`qr/.../` operator](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlop.pod#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) should instead be used. Rather than figure out the interpolation rules as part of a code cleanup, one can instead debug the regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use re 'debugcolor';

my $blah = "[\\?!()\";/\\|‘]";

print "something\n" if "not important" =~ m/$blah/;
```

This run shows the regex as `[\?!()%";/\|%x{e2}%x{80}%x{98}]`, with the wacky `%x` bits indicating that the `‘` is actually a smart quote; some software along the way has (probably) corrupted this code. Fun! As for the fix, rewrite the code to use `qr`, and then verify the new code with `re`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use re 'debugcolor';

my $blah = qr#[?!()";/|']#;
use Data::Dumper; warn Dumper $blah;

print "something\n" if "not important" =~ m/$blah/;
```

I'll leave it to you to decide whether `\` should be part of the regex, and to ponder why it appears to be listed twice. There are unit tests and documentation for this code, right?

Comment: With that smart quote, if you `use utf8;` then: `[\?!()%";/\|%x{2018}]`